# Fedora: Xorg login sequence under gdm

Tags: fedora, xorg

Fedora 28+, `i3` window manager.  My login scripts are all predicated upon the whole Xorg session startup sequence (`~/.xinitrc`, `~/.xsession`, *etc.*), but at some point in upgrading my old FC23 laptop to FC28, `gdm` became the default and my startup scripts don't run any more.

It looks like `gdm` is `systemd`-based, so getting my scripts back in the login sequence can probably happen if I can figure out how to:

1. Figure out how the `systemd` session startup sequence used by `gdm` maps to the old `Xorg` one, and write my own user `systemd` modules to plug into the appropriate places in the sequence.  So far I haven't found any sort of mapping between the X user session startup sequence and the `gdm` one.  (*Assuming `systemd` user modules can intermix with the system modules in the sequence.*)  Or,
2. Disable the `gdm` service and get `Xorg` started instead.  This would be a regression to old-style stuff, and probably not the preferred solution.  I should learn how the current mechanism works rather than clinging to legacy stuff -- but if the current mechanism can't provide the hook-points I need, I may have to [find out how to] disable `gdm` and start `Xorg` instead.

My scripts do things like set up envariables to be inherited, start particular dæmons and agents, and suchlike -- so that it's all in place by the time the first user application gets started by me.

Does anyone have an answer to either of these, or have an alternate solution to propose?

Thanks!

Comment: Try putting your stuff in `~/.xprofile`, it should be sourced from `/etc/gdm3/Xsession` -- unfortunately I cannot test it right now. Btw, this has nothing to do with systemd -- not *everything* wrong in this world is caused by systemd ;-)

Comment: Notice that gdm may run your session through `ssh-agent`, which is a setgid program and will wipe off some environment variables, like `LD_PRELOAD`.

Comment: It’s not clear what you are asking. “gdm” was used in Fedora 23 too, although it has change a bit it still starts using the same mechanism. Are you asking how to disable gdm and switch to the text console login, where you can then run “startx”?  Or do you want to use an alternate login manager such as lightdm or sddm?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` to force `gdm` to use `Xorg` instead of `wayland`, which it uses by default.

Add or uncomment this in there:

```
[daemon]
WaylandEnable=false
```

If `i3` also uses `wayland`, you may need to change its configuration as well.
Refer to the `i3` documentation on how to do that (I don't have experience with `i3`).

Comment: @mosvy -- I've done that, and I get this in the journal during session startup: `/usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[<pid>]: /bin/sh: line 0: exec: --: invalid option` but I can't figure out which file it's trying to execute.  Even with debugging enabled in `/etc/gdm/custome.conf` it doesn't make clear that it's even getting to `/etc/gdm/Xsession`,